# Linear regression - water column correction

Tags: water

I am curious what the best way is to do a **linear regression** between depth (y) and b2/b3 radiance (x). My goal is to **derive the slope and y-intercept** to plug into the equation z = m1*ln(b2/b3) - m0 [m1:slope, m0:y-int].

How do I plot the depth and corresponding reflectance in blue/green in a linear regression to get slope/y-intercept?

```py
//Import images
var s2 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR");

// Cloud processing 
// Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
var cloudBitMask = ee.Number(2).pow(10).int();
var cirrusBitMask = ee.Number(2).pow(11).int();

function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');
  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0).and(
            qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));
  return image.updateMask(mask);
}

// 2020 Cloud masked image
var cloudMasked_2020 = s2
  .filterDate('2020-01-01','2020-12-30')
  .filterBounds(Belize1)
  .map(maskS2clouds)
  .select(['B2','B3','B4','B5','B6','B7'],['blue','green','red','nir','swir1','swir2'])
  .median()

Map.addLayer(cloudMasked_2020, {bands: ['red', 'blue', 'green'], max: 2000}, '2020');


//---------- CALCULATE REFLECTANCE VALUES --------------
// get reflectance values at a particular point (geometry)
var pixelVals5 = cloudMasked_2020.reduceRegion(
    {reducer: ee.Reducer.toList(), geometry: depthFive, scale: 2000});
    
var pixelVals10 = cloudMasked_2020.reduceRegion(
    {reducer: ee.Reducer.toList(), geometry: depthTen, scale: 2000});

// extract reflectance for blue band
var reflectance5_b2 = pixelVals5.toArray(['blue']).multiply(1000);
var reflectance10_b2 = pixelVals10.toArray(['blue']).multiply(1000);

// extract reflectance for green band
var reflectance5_b3 = pixelVals5.toArray(['green']).multiply(1000);
var reflectance10_b3 = pixelVals10.toArray(['green']).multiply(1000);

//divide blue/green and then calculate log (log(b2/b3))
var blue_div_green = (ee.Array.cat([reflectance5_b2.divide(reflectance5_b3),
                      reflectance10_b2.divide(reflectance10_b3)],1)).log()

// import depths from ground-truth
var depths = ee.Array([[5,10]])

// concatenate depths with blue/green ratios
var all_depth_reflectance = ee.Array.cat([blue_div_green,depths])
```

This is a link to my script: https://code.earthengine.google.com/5eb66d2431f46780619653e684ba8249

I am also curious if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  It emphasizes that there should be only one question asked per question.  I recommend reviewing http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/a/3353/115 for tips on how to structure a good question.

Comment: For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.